# react-redux app: returning a redux prop in jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a list which I saved as a state and when I use it to output jsx it works perfectly. However, if I use a global list and try to pass it via redux and display the list in JSX  it gives me an `Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {btnId, audioId, keyCode, source, type}).` error. I read in a previous post that one can't dispatch to JSX, which might be the reason it is not working. However, I can I make it work so that it works using redux. My code is below:

List:

```
    this.state = {
      displayTxt : "Welcome to my digital Drum Machine",
      localSoundList : [
        {
          btnId : "gitarreStrumm1",
          audioId : "Q",
          keyCode : 81,
          source : "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-1.mp3",
          type : "audio/mpeg"
        },
        {
          btnId : "gitarreStrumm2",
          audioId : "W",
          keyCode : 87,
          source : "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-2.mp3",
          type : "audio/mpeg"
        },
        {
          btnId : "gitarreStrumm3",
          audioId : "E",
          keyCode : 69,
          source : "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-3.mp3",
          type : "audio/mpeg"
        },
        {
          btnId : "gitarreStrumm4",
          audioId : "A",
          keyCode : 65,
          source : "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-4_1.mp3",
          type : "audio/mpeg"
        },   
        {
          btnId : "clap",
          audioId : "S",
          keyCode : 83,
          source : "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-6.mp3",
          type : "audio/mpeg"
        },
        {
          btnId : "hat",
          audioId : "D",
          keyCode : 68,
          source : "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Dsc_Oh.mp3",
          type : "audio/mpeg"
        },
        {
          btnId : "hiKick",
          audioId : "Z",
          keyCode : 90,
          source : "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Kick_n_Hat.mp3",
          type : "audio/mpeg"
        },
        {
          btnId : "loKick",
          audioId : "X",
          keyCode : 88,
          source : "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/RP4_KICK_1.mp3",
          type : "audio/mpeg"
        },
        {
          btnId : "hihat",
          audioId : "C",
          keyCode : 67,
          source : "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Cev_H2.mp3",
          type : "audio/mpeg"
        }        
      ]
    };
```

the function I use is as follows. Please note that I already used bind for this in the constructor.

```
      createPads(){
        return this.state.localSoundList.map((item) => {
          return (<div class="col-sm-4">
              {console.log(item.audioId)}
              <div id={item.btnId} class="btn btn-primary btn-sm drum-pad" onClick={this.clickButton} value={item.audioId}>
                {item.audioId}
                <audio id={item.audioId} class="clip" src={item.source} type={item.type}></audio>
              </div>
            </div>);                        
        });
      }
```

Now, for redux I created a global list:

```
let mySoundList = {
    displayTxt : "Welcome to my digital Drum Machine",
    localSoundList : [
      {
        btnId : "gitarreStrumm1",
        audioId : "Q",
        keyCode : 81,
        source : "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-1.mp3",
        type : "audio/mpeg"
      },
      {
        btnId : "gitarreStrumm2",
        audioId : "W",
        keyCode : 87,
        source : "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-2.mp3",
        type : "audio/mpeg"
      },
      {
        btnId : "gitarreStrumm3",
        audioId : "E",
        keyCode : 69,
        source : "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-3.mp3",
        type : "audio/mpeg"
      },
      {
        btnId : "gitarreStrumm4",
        audioId : "A",
        keyCode : 65,
        source : "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-4_1.mp3",
        type : "audio/mpeg"
      },   
      {
        btnId : "clap",
        audioId : "S",
        keyCode : 83,
        source : "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-6.mp3",
        type : "audio/mpeg"
      },
      {
        btnId : "hat",
        audioId : "D",
        keyCode : 68,
        source : "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Dsc_Oh.mp3",
        type : "audio/mpeg"
      },
      {
        btnId : "hiKick",
        audioId : "Z",
        keyCode : 90,
        source : "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Kick_n_Hat.mp3",
        type : "audio/mpeg"
      },
      {
        btnId : "loKick",
        audioId : "X",
        keyCode : 88,
        source : "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/RP4_KICK_1.mp3",
        type : "audio/mpeg"
      },
      {
        btnId : "hihat",
        audioId : "C",
        keyCode : 67,
        source : "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Cev_H2.mp3",
        type : "audio/mpeg"
      }        
    ]
  };
```

this is the function where I get the "child error":

```
    return this.props.addSound(mySoundList.localSoundList.map((item) => {
      return (<div class="col-sm-4">
          {console.log(item.audioId)}
          <div id={item.btnId} class="btn btn-primary btn-sm drum-pad" onClick={this.clickButton} value={item.audioId}>
            {item.audioId}
            <audio id={item.audioId} class="clip" src={item.source} type={item.type}></audio>
          </div>
        </div>);                        
    }));
```

then I display everything in the render function of react:

```
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              { this.createPads() }                     
            </div>
          </div>
```

Here is the llink to my codepen:

https://codepen.io/roger1891/pen/LaYYaN?editors=0010

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the expected behavior of your app is but the error you get come from the fact that in the second case, you return the result of the `addSound` function. This function return an object (`with keys {btnId, audioId, keyCode, source, type}`) but a react element is expected there.

Your code seems to run well if you remove the `addSound`function in the function with `child error`:

```
return mySoundList.localSoundList.map((item) => {
  return (<div class="col-sm-4">
      {console.log(item.audioId)}
      <div id={item.btnId} class="btn btn-primary btn-sm drum-pad" onClick={this.clickButton} value={item.audioId}>
        {item.audioId}
        <audio id={item.audioId} class="clip" src={item.source} type={item.type}> 
     </audio>
      </div>
    </div>);                        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that the logic of your code is getting a bit tangled up.

If you change `{ this.createPads() }` to `{ console.log(this.createPads()) }` you can see in the console output that you're trying to render the redux action object, not a react component.

The problem is in the function `createPads`:

```
createPads(){
    //loops over soundlist and outputs items into html
    return this.props.addSound(mySoundList.localSoundList.map((item) => {
   // return this.state.localSoundList.map((item) => {
      return (<div class="col-sm-4">
          {console.log(item.audioId)}
          <div id={item.btnId} class="btn btn-primary btn-sm drum-pad" onClick={this.clickButton} value={item.audioId}>
            {item.audioId}
            <audio id={item.audioId} class="clip" src={item.source} type={item.type}></audio>
          </div>
        </div>);                        
    }));
  }
```

Here you're calling the dispatch function to redux, but you're passing it a redux action where the payload is a list of react components. The react components should be in your render function instead. You should pass data as payload in the redux action, and use data to render react components in the render function.

Also, since you're rendering the return value of `createPads`, this function should return react components directly instead of a list of react components wrapped in a plain javascript object.